# Datatable - Can´t call service inside custom action

Tags: datatable, angular2-services

In **Angular** i have a **[Datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)**. This datatable has a custom button and action, like this.

```
 buttons: {
         buttons: [
        {
          action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
            this.meterListCtrl.download(DATA).subscribe(
              response => {
              saveAs(response,moment_timezone(Date.now()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")+".csv")}
            )}
        }
      ],
      dom: {
          button: {
            tag: "i",
            className: "fas fa-file-excel excel pointer",
            titleAttr: 'Exportar'
          },
        }
      },
```

The problem: When i click on the bottom return  *Cannot read property 'download' of undefined* - This *.download* is a function that call a service.

So: Anybody know how can i fix this error?

Comment: Apparently meterListCtrl is undefined. Can you show us more of your code, particularly where did you define meterListCtrl?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with a some strange code... .

Declare $ to use a vanilla JS in .ts file.

```
declare var $: any;
```

Then in datatable buttons add a custom class in element className

```
buttons: {
        buttons: [
          {
            text: "Exportar"
          }
        ],
        dom: {
          button: {
            tag: "btn",
            className: "btn btn-primary export"
          }
        }
      },
```

Finally detect when this class is clicked.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".export", () => {
      this.export();
    });
```

And call export function

```
 export() {
    this.meterListCtrl
      .download(localStorage.getItem("API"))
      .subscribe(response => {
        saveAs(
          response,
          moment_timezone(Date.now()).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ".csv"
        );
      });
  }
```